# logo microdata in meta

Tags: seo, microdata

I am trying to do organisation microdata for my website but I was wondering if it is possible to put your logo into a meta tag - all examples I have see are like this:

```html
<div class="home" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <a href="/" class="nav-link" itemprop="url">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Company name">
    <meta itemprop="description" content="The best company ever">
    <img src="logo.png" itemprop="logo" alt="Company logo">
  </a>
</div>
```

However my logo is going to be made up of two sprites as they get animated to make the header smaller when you scroll down the screen so I don't actually have an image tag (and don't want to include one as it would mean an extra request for nothing)

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
<meta itemprop="logo" src="logo.png">
```

If so, what is the correct syntax - would I use `src` or `content` like with the name and description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out you use a `link` tag instead of a `meta` tag:

```
<link itemprop="logo" href="logo.png" rel="logo">
```